# How to use setter for this Kotlin class property?

Tags: java, kotlin, setter

I have the following class coded in Kotlin:

```
class MyClass {
    var color: String = ""
    var action: String = ""
    val owners = Array(1) {Owner()}

    class Owner {
        var userId: String = ""
        var userName: String = ""
    }
}
```

...and I'm accessing it Java:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.setColor("blue");
myObject.setAction("throw");
```

...and I'd like to be able to set the owner. I'm not sure how, though. If it were an object that was coded in Java with public members, I'd just do something like:

```
myObject.owners[0].userId = "001";
myObject.owners[0].userName = "Freddy"
```

Since the object was coded in Kotlin, I need to user a setter in Java.

How do I set the properties in the first element of an array with a setter?

Comment: Just call the setters right away: `myObject.getOwners()[0].setUserId("001");` and `myObject.getOwners()[0].setUserName("Freddy");`

Comment: @hotkey, as you were the first to answer, if you'd like to put that in an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Done, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each Kotlin property `foo`, you can call its getter in Java as `getFoo()` and, if the property is mutable, the setter as `setFoo(value)`.

See: [Calling Kotlin from Java — Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#properties)

In your case, just access the array with the getter, take its item and call the setters: `myObject.getOwners()[0].setUserId("001");` and `myObject.getOwners()[0].setUserName("Freddy");`, or assign the `Owner` to a local variable:

```
MyClass.Owner owner = myObject.getOwners()[0];
owner.setUserId("001");
owner.setUserName("Freddy");
```

Comment: Regarding declaring `owner` in your example, is `Owner` class accessible from Java, since it's internal to `MyClass`?

Comment: Thanks, fixed it: you can reference the class as `MyClass.Owner`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getOwners` which will return `owners` object then set the value.

```
myObject.getOwners()[0].setUserId("001");
myObject.getOwners()[0].setUserName("Freddy");
```